# VBA macro to save excel file using path from cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to save out a file using a combination of hard line and cell value to determine the file path.

In cell `A29`, I have a formula that outputs this:

> 2014\January\High Cash 1.7.14

I'm getting an *Expected: end of statement* error.

The code is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="S:\IRD\Tamarac\Daily High Cash Reporting\& Range("A29").Text & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _  xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _ , CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting of SO already shows the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would re-write as follows:

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "S:\IRD\Tamarac\Daily High Cash Reporting\" & Range("A29").Text & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

I think all you are missing is the closing double-quotes after the 'Reporting\' part of your code...

Comment: Actually, I'm copying your code now and its giving me an error on the "_" after FileFormat... help?

Comment: Try Removing the "_ " before the xlNormal and before CreateBackup.  I've edited my suggested answer.

Comment: This code created an unreadable workbook for me using Excel 2007. I found the problem was with "FileFormat:=xlNormal". After changing this to "FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook", the code now works correctly and creates an excel file that Excel can read. Not sure if this is due to the version of Excel im using etc, but hope this helps anyone that stumbles here with the same problem that I had.

Answer (score 5):

Suggest you go a step further and ensure any invalid file name characters that will case a save error are filtered out

This code removes

> []/:*?"<>

*main code*

```
Sub CleanSave()
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\temp\" & strClean(Range("A29").Value) & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

*cleaning function*

```
Function strClean(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[\[\]|\/\\:\*\?""<>]"
    .Global = True
    strClean = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I use a different cleaning function but this goes into my database as well :)

Comment: Brett and @Siddharth What's the difference between declaring it as a sub and a function?