# Save Excel file to two different locations?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to save an Excel file to both my `C:` drive and to a USB stick at the same time when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this functionality doesn't exist as part of excel's native features. However, you could write a small macro which would save your file to two different locations when using a hotkey. A good example such a macro is given in the answer to the following question, you would need to adapt it to save in two locations.

[VBA macro to save excel file using path from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978868/vba-macro-to-save-excel-file-using-path-from-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the **Save** with an *Event* macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Transfer\temp.xlsm"
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\TestFolder\temp.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Dual save performed"
End Sub
```

But you would need to adjust the filespecs to suite your cases.

Because it is workbook code, it is very easy to install and use:

1. right-click the tiny Excel icon just to the left of File on the Menu Bar
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (workbook code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

If you open the VBE window first, then here is how to open the **workbook code area:**

[image]

Comment: I've tried that but no success. I opened the Excel Workbook. Pressed Alt + F11 to lauch VBE. Clicked View > Code> &copied:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\stores.xlsm"
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\stores.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Dual save performed"
End Sub

I have the file saved previously as .xlsm I go View in Excel > Macros > Record Macros. When I press Ctrl + S, the file does not save to my C & F drives?

Comment: @TrevorCarey ...............Must place the macro in the **Workbook code area.**  See my instructions

Comment: Will try that now, thought I had been doing that earlier. Will report back.

Comment: I did that Gary, then I ran the Marco and still no luck in saving it to 2 locations.

Comment: should my file be saved in .xlsm before I start doing anything with Macro and VBE?